# parse java string in java

Tags: java, parsing

I want to parse java code using java.

problem is , when I pass the java code to parse method,it does not take it as string.How do I escape the code to be parsed

```
public class JavaParser {

    private int noOfLines;

    public void parse(String javaCode){
        String[] lines = javaCode.split("[\r\n]+");
        for(String line : lines)
            System.out.println(line);
    }



     public static void main(){
            JavaParser a = new JavaParser();
            a.parse("java code;");
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the input and output of your program run? (when you don't get expected output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the java code file as a text file, line by line or alla t once for example:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("foo.java");
try {
    String everything = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
} finally {
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Then you can parse the everything string.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can describe what you're trying to achieve?

In general its java's compiler (like javac) work to parse the java source files.

Quick googling revealed [this project](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) that can suit your needs

As of java 6 you can invoke compiler as a part of your code (java exposes the compiler API). This can be helpful if you're trying to compile the code after you read it. In general you can read [this article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html), maybe you'll find it helpful

Hope this helps